# Chrome won't allow local camera access

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, html5-video

I'm trying to test out some code for accessing a webcam on an HTML page and Chrome doesn't seem to allow me to. I made an exception for the file and yet everytime I reload (which it tells me will put the settings in effect) it goes back to blocking it

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

[chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure](http://chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure)

Add your url there and enable this flag, relaunch and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can open chrome with the flag disable-web-security

For Mac, in terminal:

open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --disable-web-security

For a PC in console:

chrome.exe --disable-web-security